# Tcl_Filesystem supporting path internal representation

Tags: tcl

I am implementing Tcl_Filesystem object. My implementation supports internal path representation which could be used to efficiently access FS nodes.

I have implemented pathInFilesystemProc in a way that it returns internal representation of the path via clientDataPtr.

I wonder is it possible to extract that internal representation from pathPtr argument of statProc?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
Tcl_FSGetInternalRep

Comment: Be careful; the internal representation is only usually understandable by the code that created it.